# How to investigate Azure Function slower cold start in different region?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have a Windows-based Azure Function on consumption plan which typically has a host start time of around a second or less. This is the case everywhere apart from a single region in production where it never takes less than around 2.5 seconds, sometimes reaching 8. I've not been able to replicate the slowness locally or in any other Azure environment.

In terms of differences, the environments are configured identically as far as I can make out. The live Function has low traffic, in fact one of the test environments will have more traffic. I'm not sure why that would have any impact on start up time though and low traffic volumes don't appear to impact other environment's start up time.

The function app has a collection of different trigger types, including queue, timer, http and service bus.

I've used Visual Studio diagnostic tools to try and identify any hot paths. There are no IO calls from the user code during start up and nothing particularly intensive.

How can I go about investigating and identifying the issue?

Comment: Does the below answer helps your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get to the root cause of why I observed differing start times in different regions. The region itself wasn't the problem. Looking at the memory usage of both in Monitor exposed the underlying VM names the Functions were sat on. I realised that everywhere the application was performing well had a different pattern of name compared to everywhere that was performing badly.

The slower Functions followed the format `RD000000000000` and the better performing instances followed the format `DW0-AA0-0-0`. The former also had wild swings in available memory whereas the latter had a constant level of available memory.

I was able to fix the problem by completely tearing down the Functions and plan and redeploying. The new version was in the improved format.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that there is low traffic on the Azure function where you see slow start time. One potential reason could be be related to serverless cold start in the consumption plan. Following is the article link with detailed explanation on it.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/

Comment: I'm only looking at cold starts - the value of Job Host startup time. Which is why I don't see how traffic volume would have any effect.

Comment: Azure deallocate resources after roughly 20 minutes of inactivity of azure func. after which your next call will be a cold start. Hence a low volume has a high potential of leading you into this cold start scenario where you function is getting invoked with over 20 mins interval i.e. at 9.00 am some data hits your azure func. and then the next data invoking your azure func is at 9.20 am.

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm looking at - the cold starts. Warm requests are fine. Each cold start logs a host startup time which is what I'm investigating.

Comment: You could run this problematic function in a premium plan in that specific region for some time and see if it helps narrowing down the issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal

Answer (score 0):

*Since, you mentioned that there are function app instances in different locations, **I suspect that your function app is using/calling a resource which is far away from it's own location** and hence it is taking time.*

Further, I would suggest you to remote debug your function app using [**Visual Studio Remote Debugger**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure?view=vs-2019) and see what line of code actually takes time in that region. This will give you the bottleneck.

Comment: Cross-region calls did cross my mind. I've double checked though and the storage account is in the same location. There are no IO calls on startup so not sure what else it could be. I've also deployed the app to the same region and not been able to replicated the slow starts. I'll give remote debugger a go.

Comment: Sure, try and let me know.

Comment: Does the answer helps your query?

Comment: I managed to fix the problem described in my accepted answer.